# add new tag in response soap

Tags: xml, groovy, soap

**what i already tried:** i created code using groovy like this:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement()
class Input {
    @XmlElement(name = "memberCode", required = true, namespace = "java:financial.sekuritas.pt.com.doReceivePushData")
    String memberCode
    @XmlElement(name = "fileContents", required = true, namespace = "java:financial.sekuritas.pt.com.doReceivePushData")
    String fileContents
    @XmlElement(name = "crc32", required = true, namespace = "java:financial.sekuritas.pt.com.doReceivePushData")
    String crc32
    @XmlElement(name = "urlWS", required = true, namespace = "java:financial.sekuritas.pt.com.doReceivePushData")
    String urlWS

}

@Transactional
@GrailsCxfEndpoint(address = "/doReceivePushData")
class ReportInvestorAccountCIMBService {    
    @Resource WebServiceContext context
    @WebMethod(operationName = "doReceivePushData")
    @WebResult(header = true, name = "iniwebresult")
    @ResponseWrapper(localName="iniresponsewrapper")
    public String doReceivePushData(@WebParam(name = 'input') 
    @XmlElement(name = "input", required = true, namespace = "http://financial.sekuritas.pt.com/") Input Input)

    { 
       return 1
    }
        
}
```

**result**

in the result wsdl **response** from that code is like this:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <doReceivePushDataResponse>
      <iniresponsewrapper/>
      <iniwebresult>string</iniwebresult>
    </doReceivePushDataResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

**the desired form of response**

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
      <soap:Body>
        <doReceivePushDataResponse>
          <iniresponsewrapper>
          <iniwebresult>string</iniwebresult>
         </iniresponsewrapper>
        </doReceivePushDataResponse>
      </soap:Body>
    </soap:Envelope>
```

**how**

how do i can get **response**
like above?

I've spent a lot of time on this, if anyone is willing to help I would really appreciate it

Comment: just create an class for your response and return it instead of "String". like in this example: https://github.com/Grails-Plugin-Consortium/grails-cxf#returning-domain-classes

Comment: thankyou for helping me, can u give example for my case?